# installation psycopg2 on MAC with error: pg_config executable not found

Tags: postgresql, macos, psycopg2

I need your help with installation `psycopg2` on MAC.

1. I've already installed:

   - **Python 3.7.3** as a part of Anaconda environment
   - **Postgres.app** from https://postgresapp.com
2. When I'm trying to install psycopg2 package a terminal show me an error

```
    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
```

I've read a number of articles where they recommend to provide `$PATH` before installing `psycopg2`, but the problem is in a fact that `Postgres.app` doesn't create the `pg_config` directory:

*/Users/konstantin_klychkov/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-12*

Comment: Why not using anaconda packages ? https://anaconda.org/anaconda/psycopg2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the problem is in a fact that Postgres.app doesn't create pg_config directory:
>   */Users/konstantin_klychkov/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-12*

I think you may be looking in the wrong place.  `pg_config` is not a directory, but a program.  Try putting `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin` in your `$PATH`:

```
$ ls /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin | grep pg_config
pg_config
```